# How to trigger class function using button in react navigation 5 header?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation-v5

I have this class component below. I need to trigger a function in my class from the navigation header. Nothing happens when I click 'TEST'. If I replace `this.triggerFunction` with `console.log("TEST") or something` then it works.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons here documentation gives an example for functional component but I cannot find anything about class one.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
   ...


  async componentDidMount() {
    ...
    
    this.props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.triggerFunction}>
            <Text>TEST<Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ),
    });
  }

   
    triggerFunction = () => {
      console.log('inside header function');
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';

class Home extends React.Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => {
                return (<View>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.triggerFunction}>
                                <Text>TEST<Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        );
              }
        });
      }

  triggerFunction = () => {
    console.log('inside header function');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';

class Home extends React.Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => {
                return (<View>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.triggerFunction}>
                                <Text>TEST<Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        );
              }
        });
      }

  triggerFunction = () => {
    console.log('inside header function');
  };
}
```

Please give it a try. Please get back to me if it is not working.

Comment: thanks for the comment. It didn't make any difference.

Comment: @likeachamp make <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.triggerFunction}> to <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.triggerFunction}> , also triggerFunction must be outside componentDidMount

Comment: It's actually outside componentDidAmount but I made a mistake while copying here. However, onPress={this.triggerFunction} worked as you mentioned. Please update your answer than I will mark that as correct. Thanks